# Choosing between NullPointerException and IllegalArgumentException for signalling error at object construction

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a question about best practices in Java. I'm writing a class, which relies on an object at construction pretty heavily. In fact, if the object passed in at construction is null, most of the functionality wouldn't make sense. I thought it best to throw an exception in the case where null is passed as an argument at object construction, but I don't know what the most appropriate exception would be in this case. Should I throw a NullPointer, IllegalArgument, Instatiation, or even an Initialization exception.

I've seen these all used throughout the Java source codebase, and I don't seem to be able to distinguish why a NullPointer was used in some cases and IllegalArgument used in others. I personally would have thought that if a bad argument is passed in at construction, some initialization error should occur.

Comment: If you're doing anything to the object, Java will thrown the NPE itself.

Comment: Very true Mong, but I'd like to tell the client immediately. This will catch any errors before they become hidden at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IllegalArgument makes it clear, to the developer who's used the code, what the problem is and how to fix it I would say. It also makes it clear that the method CANNOT work without that object.

NullPointer means they have to think a little bit about what the problem is (not much) and may mean the code is cleaner, but like I said above. It's not immediately clear, from a documentation point-of-view whether your code can work with a null value or not.

Comment: Congratulations Disco, your answer got chosen over Jon Skeet's.

Comment: I prefer to leave NullPointerExceptions to the VM and never throw them explicitly.  Thus parameter checks would throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Yeah, I hope I didn't offend Jon Skeet by not accepting his answer, but I figured Disco could use the rep points a little more.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should *absolutely* throw an exception. It's simply the Right Thing To Do.

As for whether you should throw `IllegalArgumentException` or `NullPointerException` - Josh Bloch talks about this in Effective Java, and generally concludes that `NullPointerException` is a reasonable choice. I'm not entirely sure I agree (I would probably have picked `IllegalArgumentException`), but ultimately it's unlikely to matter: you shouldn't be catching either of these exceptions directly, and the stack trace will show you where there's a problem anyway.

(It's a shame Java doesn't have the equivalent to .NET's [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx), which means exactly what it sounds like.)

Personally I'm a big fan of Guava's [`Preconditions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class:

```
public class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;

  public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = Preconditions.checkNotNull(bar);
  }
}
```

(Sometimes used with a static import of `checkNotNull`.)

Comment: +1: nothing stops you from creating your own `ArgumentNullException`. Clients shouldn't catch it anyway....

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException` is used when you are expecting a valid object but get `null` instead.  This is especially pertinent when trying to call methods on a `null` object.  This is the most common use for it.  However, your case may also warrant it.

`IllegalArgumentException` is used when you received an argument into a method that is not what you expect or of the wrong type/style/etc.  This, *in my view*, would be more appropriate in your case.  You expect a valid object, but you received `null` as an argument.  This argument value is invalid - so I would throw `IllegalArgumentException` and in the message of the exception specify what's wrong, e.g.:

```
public MyClass(InputObject obj) {
    if(obj == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null passed to MyClass constructor");
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think the platform exceptions do not give the client the right amount of information to understand and fix the issue, you can create your own exception that's more appropriate in that regard, say like .NET's `ArgumentNullException`; which will tell the client both **what the problem is** and **how to fix it**.